# FATAL_ERROR System.SObjectException: Field is not writeable: Monthly_Finance__c.Project__c

Tags: apex, master-detail, dmlexception

```java
public with sharing class CSVController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static string loadCSVData(Id contentDocumentId, string fileType){
        ContentVersion contentVersionObj = [ SELECT Id, VersionData FROM 
                                             ContentVersion WHERE 
                                             ContentDocumentId =:contentDocumentId WITH USER_MODE ];
        
        list<account> acclist=new list<Account>();
        list<Monthly_Finance__c> monthlist=new list<Monthly_Finance__c>();
         
        String data= contentVersionObj.VersionData.toString();

        string[] csvFileLines=data.split('\n');
        Boolean isInsert = true;

        if(fileType == 'NFR'){
            for(Integer i=1;i<csvFileLines.size();i++){
            
                string[] csvRecordData = csvFileLines[i].split(',');
    
                Account accObj = new Account() ;            
                Monthly_Finance__c monthObj = new Monthly_Finance__c();
                
                accObj.Project_No__c = String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[0]) ? Integer.valueOf(csvRecordData[0]) : null;
                accObj.name = csvRecordData[1] ;
                accObj.Total_WIP__c = String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[3]) ? decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[3]) : null;
                accObj.Total_Debtors__c = String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[4]) ? decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[4]) : null;
                accObj.Total_Net_WIP__c = String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[5]) ? decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[5]) : null;
                accObj.Total_Net_Debtors__c = String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[6]) ? decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[6]) : null;
                accObj.PTD_GFR__c = String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[20]) ? decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[20]) : null;
                accObj.PTD_NFR__c = String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[21]) ? decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[21]) : null;
    
                monthObj.Project_No__c = String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[0]) ? Integer.valueOf(csvRecordData[0]) : null;
                monthObj.Name = csvRecordData[1];
                monthObj.April__c = String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[7]) ? decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[7]) : null;
                monthObj.May__c = String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[8]) ? decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[8]) : null;
                monthObj.June__c = String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[9]) ? decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[9]) : null;
                monthObj.July__c = String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[10]) ? decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[10]) : null;
                monthObj.August__c = String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[11]) ? decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[11]) : null;
                monthObj.September__c = String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[12]) ? decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[12]) : null;
                monthObj.October__c = String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[13]) ? decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[13]) : null;
                monthObj.November__c = String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[14]) ? decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[14]) : null;
                monthObj.December__c = String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[15]) ? decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[15]) : null;
                monthObj.Januray__c = String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[16]) ? decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[16]) : null;
                monthObj.February__c = String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[17]) ? decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[17]) : null;
                monthObj.March__c = String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[18].trim()) ? decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[18].trim()) : null;
                    
                    
                acclist.add(accObj);   
                monthlist.add(monthObj);   
            }
        }else if(fileType == 'Forecast'){
            for(Integer i=1;i<csvFileLines.size();i++){
            
                string[] csvRecordData = csvFileLines[i].split(',');
    
                Account accObj = new Account() ;            
                Monthly_Finance__c monthObj = new Monthly_Finance__c();

                List<Monthly_Finance__c> existingRecord = [SELECT Id,Name, Project_No__c,April_Forecast__c,May_Forecast__c,
                                                            June_Forecast__c FROM Monthly_Finance__c Where Project_No__c =: decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[0]) 
                                                            LIMIT 1 ];

                
                if(existingRecord.isEmpty()){
                    isInsert = true;
                    Account accountObject = new Account() ;            
                    Monthly_Finance__c monthObject = new Monthly_Finance__c();

                    accountObject.Project_No__c = String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[0]) ? Integer.valueOf(csvRecordData[0]) : null;
                    accountObject.name = csvRecordData[1] ;
                    accountObject.Total_WIP__c = String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[5]) ? decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[5]) : null;
        
                    
                    monthObject.Name = csvRecordData[1];
                    monthObject.April_Forecast__c = String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[7]) ? decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[7]) : null;
                    monthObject.May_Forecast__c = String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[8]) ? decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[8]) : null;
                    monthObject.June_Forecast__c = String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[9]) ? decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[9]) : null;
                    //monthObject.July__c = String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[10]) ? decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[10]) : null;
                    // monthObject.August__c = String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[11]) ? decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[11]) : null;
                    // monthObject.September__c = String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[12]) ? decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[12]) : null;
                    // monthObject.October__c = String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[13]) ? decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[13]) : null;
                    // monthObject.November__c = String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[14]) ? decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[14]) : null;
                    // monthObject.December__c = String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[15]) ? decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[15]) : null;
                    // monthObject.Januray__c = String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[16]) ? decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[16]) : null;
                    // monthObject.February__c = String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[17]) ? decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[17]) : null;
                    // monthObject.March__c = String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[18].trim()) ? decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[18].trim()) : null;


                    acclist.add(accountObject);   
                    monthlist.add(monthObject);
                }else{
                    isInsert = false;

                    monthObj = existingRecord[0];
                    monthObj.April_Forecast__c = String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[7]) ? decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[7]) : null;
                    monthObj.May_Forecast__c = String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[8]) ? decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[8]) : null;
                    monthObj.June_Forecast__c = String.isNotBlank(csvRecordData[9]) ? decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[9]) : null;

                    monthlist.add(monthObj);
                    update monthlist;

                }
                 
            }
        }

        if(isInsert){
            insert acclist;
        
            for(Integer i=0; i< acclist.size();i++){
                monthlist[i].Project__c = acclist[i].Id;
            }

            insert monthlist;
        }
        return string.valueOf(acclist.size());
                                
    }
}
```

Here Account is master object and Month is detail object.
The code works fine while processing NFR data, but while processing forecast data if csv file has records where some records are already present in `Monthly_Finance__c` and some are not and should create record for those, it throws

> FATAL_ERROR System.SObjectException: Field is not writeable: Monthly_Finance__c.Project__c

note that the code works fine if the forecast data only has records to update or only has records to create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your issue is caused by the update in the second for loop `update monthlist;`.

From the description of the scenario it sounds like it is possible for monthList to contain both a month that needs to be inserted and one that needs to be updated. If on the first iteration `existingRecords.isEmpty()` is true, and then on the second iteration `existingRecords.isEmpty()` is false, then when the update it called it tries to update both of those records. It seems like this is unintended as one of them should be inserted and still needs a Project reference for the master detail relationship.

Its hard to get the full picture just from this code but that is my analysis.

I would also suggest you rework your code to remove the SOQL and DML statements from the for loop. This is considered bad practice and at scale you could run into limit issues.

Comment: Thanks Zack ! the problem was with monthlist, i cleared in the second iteration. I have made changes to SOQL and DML statements and now they are outside the loop. :)